# Matching a String Between Delimiters if and Only if it Contains a Specific ID Using REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a string between delimiters if and only if it contains the id I am looking for. For example suppose I have a text file containing several entries like the following:

```
 /id:12345, comment:"test @#$%7 *<", date:JUN-06-21/;/comment:"@#rehj%fh^?*<", date:MAR-15-20, id:11333/;/date:AUG-22-18, id:44618, comment:"&%$@#^?*!!/;
```

Let's say I want to match an entry that has the ID 44618 using REGEX. What makes this difficult is that ID can appear at the beginning, in the middle, or in the last position. The following is the REGEX I have so far but it's not working.

```
    \/\w[a-zA-Z0-9,:]*?\s?(id:44618,)\s?(\/\w[a-zA-Z0-9:;/])*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used regex to get whole entry where id can be in any position of the entry:

```
/\/[^;]*?\bid:44618\D[^;]*?;/
```

Regex in context and testbench:

```
const input = '/id:12345, comment:"test @#$%7 *<", date:JUN-06-21/;' + 
              '/comment:"@#rehj%fh^?*<", date:MAR-15-20, id:11333/;' +
              '/date:AUG-22-18, id:44618, comment:"&%$@#^?*!!/;';

const regex = /\/[^;]*?\bid:44618\D[^;]*?;/;           

alert(input.match(regex)[0]);
```

Output from alert, printing the whole entry:

```
/date:AUG-22-18, id:44618, comment:"&%$@#^?*!!/;
```

Comment: I have tested this out on REGEX101 by changing the positions of the ID in the entry from start to middle to last position and it worked. I have tried that with other answers posted here but they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only specific ID, just write in regex id and set flag "g"-global and "m" multiline
yourString.match(/id:747484/gm)
And for different ids
yourString.match(/id:\d+/gm)

Answer (score 0):

The pattern does not match anything because the first character class `[a-zA-Z0-9,:]` does not contain all the allowed characters to match until the occurrence of `id:44618` in the example string.

You could extend it for example [like this](https://regex101.com/r/zErWyx/1) but that will not match until the delimiter `/;`

Another think to note is that if the id is at the start like `/id:44618` then  matching the first word character like `\/\w` in your pattern will prevent from matching the id at all as the first character is already consumed.

You could extend the character class at the end of the pattern with all the allowed characters, but as it can also be a comment, you don't know the possible characters up front.

If the comment field is not before the id field, what you might do is assert the word character after the opening `/` using a positive lookahead `(?=\w)` and then match the id and match as least as possible chars `.*?` until the closing `/;`

```
\/(?=\w)[a-zA-Z0-9,:;\s-]*?(id:44618).*?\/;
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dC5olO/1)

If there are no other `/` allowed, you might also use a negated character class `[^/]*` matching any char except the forward slash

```
\/[^/]*(id:44618)[^/]*\/;
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ITzxRA/1)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think you may have misunderstood what I meant when I said ID can appear at the beginning, in the middle, or in the last position. What I meant was that in each entry, ID can be the first item followed by Date, followed by Comment. Or It could be the middle item. Or it could be the last item in the entry.

Comment: @EternalCuriosity The second pattern works regardless of the position as long as there is no / in between.

Comment: @EternalCuriosity See https://regex101.com/r/yTNWF3/1

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
/.*id:(\d+)/
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/BMeh3M/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  id:                      'id:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

**JavaScript code**:

```js
const string = `/id:12345, comment:"test @#$%7 *<", date:JUN-06-21/;/comment:"@#rehj%fh^?*<", date:MAR-15-20, id:11333/;/date:AUG-22-18, id:44618, comment:"&%$@#^?*!!/;`
console.log((string.match(/.*id:(\d+)/) || ['',''])[1])
```